# Finding the number of primes numbers using exclusion/inclusion principle: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

I want to find the number of primes numbers between 1 and 30 using the exclusion and inclusion principle. This is what I got:

[image]

The numbers in sky-blue are the ones I have to subtract. The others are the ones I have to add.

I got $1$ which gives me $11$ primes number below $30$, but are just $10$.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: are you possibly counting 1 in one place and not the other?

Comment: @gt6989b Does it mean I must have started counting from 2 instead of 1 (i.e., started subtracting from 29 and not from 30)?

Comment: can you elaborate on the basis of what you are using incl/excl? # of divisors?

Comment: I really have no idea what you're trying to do here, nor I understand your table. You say "...the ones I have to substract"....from **what** , **how** and **why**? How are you defining the sets of numbers to which you want to apply the I-E principle?!

Comment: You are subtracting all the multiples of 2, of 3, of 5, and so on --- including 2 itself, 3 itself, 5 itself, and so on. But those are primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that (for example) $2$ is divisible by $2$, but is prime. So in your first zone, all the composite count numbers should be one lower.

Using all primes like that in the first zone seems like you already need to know the answer before you start calculating. But you can get the answer without scanning all primes - just those up to $\sqrt {30}$ and their cross-products.

If you adjust for the prime overcount, then only use the lines corresponding to $2,3,5$, then $6,10,15$, then $30$, you get $30-(14+9+5)+(5+3+2)-(1)=11$ non-composite numbers less than or equal to $30$, which includes non-prime $1$.